# Where to store schema in Apache Solr?

Tags: xml, solr, xml-parsing, lucene, xsd

Beginner learning how to use Apache Solr. Using "Indexing data" section [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_2/tutorial.html) tutorial.

I am unable to index my "custom made XML files" to Apache Solr. However, there is no problem in indexing the example xml files that come with Apache Solr distribution package. I am new to XML and so I only know about the concept of XML Schema.

How to post my custom files ? Where does Apache Solr store xml schemas ? How to add an XML Schema to server ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solr uses [a special XML format](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) for creating the documents. You can't just send an XML document to Solr and expect it to parse it.

But you could use [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to read XML file from disk and map specific fields. There is an example in the Solr distribution, under example-DIH (rss example).

RSS example loads content from URL. To load from the file, see [the file-specific example on GitHub](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/blob/master/published/dihxml/conf/dih-definition.xml) from my book.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I understood that format and I am manually modifying the schema.xml to include my fields. Then I post the xml file and it works. Would this solution work ?